# No wifi adapter found ubuntu 18.04 dual boot with windows 10 on acer aspire 4750 with qualcom atheros ar9287

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, acer, atheros

I am a new user of ubuntu linux when I installed the Ubuntu Linux operating system, I got an obstacle on wifi with the description of "no wifi adapter".
My laptop is Acer Aspire 4750 with WiFi adapter Atheros Ar9287